# problem when using firestore with flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem when i try to access the data stored in cloud firestore , knowing that the firebase authentication is working perfectly. the debug console gives me this message

```
W/le.esi_gabsenc(18680): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.esi_gabsenc(18680): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.esi_gabsenc(18680): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.esi_gabsenc(18680): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.esi_gabsenc(18680): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.esi_gabsenc(18680): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.esi_gabsenc(18680): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.esi_gabsenc(18680): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/le.esi_gabsenc(18680): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

I'm using Samsung galaxy A50 android 10.

Comment: It's not a bug and doesn't have to do with problems with your code, do not worry. You can search  online for this log output and see the results yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The bad news is taking a cursory look seems to show that it's not a Flutter issue but a general Android issue with how Android protobufs are using hidden APIs.
>
> It's been fixed on Android 11 in
> https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/art/+/1294616/ but
> unfortunately is unlikely to be backported to older Android versions.
> A more likely scenario is plugins updating to newer transitive
> versions of protobufs. There isn't much we can do in Flutter. Using
> the IDE to hide those messages in the output is a reasonable
> workaround in the meantime such as #27095 (comment).
>
> Internal issue b/154851649. External protobuf issue
> protocolbuffers/protobuf#7337.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27095